# Enable safe mode with an external USB installer?

Tags: windows-8, boot, windows-8.1, cmd.exe, safe-mode

Is it possible to enable safe mode with a USB Windows Installer or Recovery Drive?

For Windows 8.1.

Comment: Here it is :- please follow the blog http://www.fixedbyvonnie.com/2013/10/how-to-boot-windows-8-into-safe-mode/ and if this fixe it , I will add it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with another Windows 8.1 computer using the Recovery Drive tool, however both Windows environments must be the same build (version and language) to make the Safe Mode option appear.

The Recovery Drive makes a bootable usb that enables the usual troubleshooting tools, these useful options are not available in a USB/DVD installation disk unfortunately.

As for anyone trying to repair a Windows environment in Safe Mode and being unable to manually select it, or without access to another identical Windows machine (to create a Recovery Drive):

You can use the Windows DVD/USB Installer to create a new partition, make a Recovery Drive and proceed to troubleshoot. Alternatively the not so useful Reset and Refresh options are always at your disposal.

Answer (score -1):

Windows + R keys

Type “msconfig” and press Enter

Click the Boot tab. Check the “Safe boot” box and select “Minimal” for a typical safe boot. Click Apply and your computer will boot into Safe Mode next time it restarts

Step By Step Method :
How to BOOT WINDOWS 8 INTO SAFE MODE
http://finally-found-the-solution.blogspot.com/2015/02/windows-8-cant-boot-into-safe-mode.html

Comment: That does imply booting Windows prior safe mode. The question is about enabling safe mode with an external USB installer.